# getting error on localhost Warning: preg_match(): Null byte in regex in C:\xampp\htdocs\pamper\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5233

Tags: errors

I'm getting this error on my every localhost WordPress projects.
and it is not allowing me to log in to the wp-admin panel.
I'm searching on google but not getting any answer.

The error is `Warning: preg_match(): Null byte in regex in C:\xampp\htdocs\pamper\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5233`
[image]

Please help??

Comment: It's impossible to tell what is causing the issue without knowing the details. Please also share these details, when did it start to occur, what did you before this, what happens if you disable plugins, and more.

Comment: I'm trying to access the folder from htdocs which I have my WordPress project in it. But when I Try to access my project form chrome browser it will open, but also be throwing above error. and I'm not able to login in into admin panel. and this is happening with all the Wordpress project in the htdocs folder. in every project, I'm getting the same error. If someone has the answer, please help.